# SoapUI Mock Server on AWS EC2 with Load Balancer SSL

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I’m trying to setup a SoapUI Mock Service on an AWS EC2 Windows instance with a Load Balancer that has an SSL certificate. The problem I’m encountering is I cannot connect to the Mock Server from my ReadyAPI desktop application.

I have successfully setup the same SoapUI Mock Service on an AWS EC2 Windows instance without a Load Balancer. What I did is I just created a SoapUI Project with 3 operations and generated their corresponding mock services; I assigned port 9090 which I also opened in Windows Firewall. I run the mock services and connect ReadyAPI from my desktop using the endpoint (http://EC2-IP Address:9090); I was able to sent request and received response from the mock services in my AWS EC2 Windows instance. But this same procedure fails for my EC2 windows instance that has a Load Balancer and an SSL certificate.

I have my AWS EC2 Certificate .PEM file, from which I generated a Private and Public key using PuTTY Key Generator, I tried to use both keys on ReadyAPI keystore but it asked for a password which I don’t remember creating when I created the AWS certificate keyPair .PEM file. I also tried to register the generated Putty Private key in Windows Certificates but it cannot recognize the file type with .ppk extension.

I believe I'm still missing some steps, I’m hoping the community can point me to the right direction as to  what to research and use. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I need a "Custom TCP Rule" in the EC2 Security Group Inbound permission for port 9090. After I added this, I was then able to connect to my Mock Service.

Comment: Which load balancer did you use.  Was it clb or alb